# Transaction Scope in Oracle with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, transactions, transactionscope

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
TableAdapter.Insert("test","test");
ts.Complete();
}
```

I am getting this error :Unable to load DLL '**oramts.dll**': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I have Oracle Client installed with Oracle services for Windows Transaction
even the DLL file **oramts.dll** is in [ORALCE_HOME]/bin

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the oracle data provider for .net installed and functioning properly?

Comment: Also what version of the Oracle Client are you working with?

Comment: Oracle9 and I am using System.Data.OracleClient not ODP.NET

Comment: Is the oracle bin in your system path statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jelle.druyts.net/2006/06/25/UnableToLoadOramtsdllTryTheReleaseVersion.aspx

> It turns out that the version of oramts.dll (which provides DTC
>   transaction support for Oracle) as installed by the Oracle 9i Release
>   2 CD is a debug build, rather than a release build. (Let that sink in
>   for a moment: Oracle is shipping debug builds of their software...).
>   As you can see in the following screenshot of the dll in
>   DependencyWalker, this debug build has a dependency on MSVCRTD.DLL,
>   which is a debug build of the Microsoft C Runtime Library

This solved my issue